# angularjs dynamically change model binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 forms - a billing and a shipping.  If the user checks a checkbox, the shipping address should be populated with the billing address and turn disabled.  If the user unchecks the box, the shipping address should be blank and return to enabled.

I have this working right now with $watch but it feels hacky.  I have 2 $watches nested in eachother watching the same element.  I want to know if there is a better way to achieve what I am doing.

I tried using a ternary operator in the ng-model like below but that didn't work either.

```
<input ng-model="isSameAsBilling ? billName : shipName" ng-disabled="isSameAsBilling" />
```

[A plunkr of my "working" code](http://plnkr.co/edit/RFjmqJ9q8E0t8DBTMhEd?p=preview)

**HTML:**

```
<input ng-model="billName" />

<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isSameAsBilling" ng-click="sameAsBillingClicked()"/>

<input ng-model="shipName" ng-disabled="isSameAsBilling" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$scope.isSameAsBilling = false;

$scope.sameAsBillingClicked = function(){
  $scope.isSameAsBilling = !$scope.isSameAsBilling;
};

$scope.$watch('isSameAsBilling', function(isSame){

  if ($scope.isSameAsBilling) {

    var shipNameWatcher = $scope.$watch('billName', function (newShipName) {
      $scope.shipName = $scope.billName;

      var secondBillWatcher = $scope.$watch('isSameAsBilling', function(isChecked){
        if (!isChecked){
          shipNameWatcher();
          secondBillWatcher();
          $scope.shipName = '';
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've finally got what you're after here.

When the checkbox is checked, it registers a $watch on the `billName` and mirrors it to the `shipName`.

When the checkbox is unchecked, the deregisters the $watch and clears the `shipName`

```
angular

  .module('app', [])

  .controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.isSameAsBilling = false;

    $scope.isSameChanged = function() {
      if ($scope.isSameAsBilling) {
        // register the watcher when checked
        $scope.nameWatcher = $scope.$watch('billName', function(bName) {
          $scope.shipName = bName
        })
      } else {
        // deregister the watcher and clear the shipName when unchecked
        $scope.nameWatcher();
        $scope.shipName = ''
      }
    }

  }]);
```

and here is the [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/h8ic8vvjGYN8nU2mbn5H?p=preview)

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that you only capture that value in time.  If you check the checkbox, the content will copy over but if you type something into billName, it won't reflect into shipName.

Comment: Ah, lightbulb. Okay I get what the problem really is. Let me think on that

Comment: Okay, you can do it with 2 watches, but they don't need to be nested. One watch on the billName that updates the shipName if the box is checked, and one on the checkbox value as I had before. [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5QVl1iiKGFQe6AgVaAiF?p=preview)